# OpenGraph: custom properties not showing in post

Tags: facebook, post, facebook-opengraph

I've create a Custom Object/Action/Aggregations for my app.

https://graph.facebook.com/10151038251679973

All is working fine but now I wanted to add custom properties for my object.

I've successfully added two properties: when and facility.

The problem is that when I share the object (i.e. posting the link on my wall) the custom properties does not show up.

Any idea? I have to do some additional configurations?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Custom properties are not showed for just posted object, but you can display 'em with your actions. You should specify something like `{match.when}` in the "Caption" field in Action Settings (Configure story attachment section):

[image: Action Settings]

Once action referencing `match` object (and caption as described above) published you will see something like this:

[image: Published action]

**BTW**, Some notes regarding warnings you see in debug tool related to Date format:
Currently where is no way to get rid of that message other that provide numeric `timestamp` instead of `ISO 8601` date (none of samples or formats described for DateTime in [Simple Types](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/simpletypes/) are working without a warning) . The good news that date is updated correctly even if warning displayed, so you may ignore such warning as long as `timestamp` displayed in  Object Properties of Debug Tool output is correct and represent your actual date. There is couple of bugs exists for that issue: [#159315504193810](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/159315504193810) and [#302542186507947](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/302542186507947)

Comment: I'll try, unfortunately my action will need a new review.
Thank you for now, I hope this works.

Comment: @Mangiucugna, admins/developers/test-users of your application can test the action before it's get approved.

Comment: Yeah, you're right...
BTW it worked!!!
I've another little question, I can translate the text that I put in the caption? I think so but I didn't find the text in the translation tool..

Answer (score 0):

See the Facebook Debugger output here:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sportilia.com%2Fg%2Fpartite%2F183%3Ffb_utente%3D5

Looks like your date format might be messing things up.

Comment: Hi thank for your response, I've seen the message but other OG object with the same issue works fine.
Moreover, the time format is fine (ISO 8601 format as FB documentation) probably is an error of the parser.

Comment: @arturnt, message about date format is just a warning. And the property is populated with correct data

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that when I share the object (i.e. posting the link on my wall) the custom properties does not show up.

I’m not sure if they are supposed to show up when you only share a *link* to the object on your wall.

Have you tried publishing an action for your object? When that creates a story, they should show up in there.

Go into your app settings, edit the object, and on the bottom have a look at the preview object (might have to create one first, if there’s no preview object yet). Edit it, add some values for your custom properties to it – they should show up there (at least that’s what I’m seeing when testing it with one of mine).